# Creating a "normal" line chart in amcharts.js with arrays?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, amcharts

I'm growing desperate with amCharts doing the simplest task. Well, at least what I think is simple. I want to create a normal line chart with "normal" data. What do I mean with normal? Well, having an array with my y values, and maybe also one for x:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,6,7,8]
```

Shouldn't it be pretty easy to put something like this in a chart? And still I'm sitting here having no idea how to do this properly(!) in amcharts. I'm using Flask (Python) and can use jsonify to get my arrays into JSON files and send it to the client, but I'm not able to go any further.

Any ideas? I mean, shouldn't this be the most basic task? But all examples using amCharts doing special stuff with date formats for x..

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, if you are looking at plotting a line graph out of arbitrary X and Y coordinates (as opposed plotting series-based data), you're better off using XY chart than serial one.

Also, amCharts will not be able to plot data in separate arrays of coordinates.

You can either convert the data to a proper format at the moment of generation of data, so it looks like this:

```
chartData = [ {
  x: 1,
  y: 5
}, {
  x: 2,
  y: 6
}, {
  x: 3,
  y: 7
}, {
  x: 4,
  y: 8
}];
```

Or add some code that converts your data to amCharts-compatible data **before** supplying it to the chart:

```
/**
 * Source data
 */
var x = [1,2,3,4];
var y = [5,6,7,8];

/**
 * Convert source data to AmCharts-compatible format
 */
var chartData = [];
for( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
  chartData.push( {
    "x": x[ i ],
    "y": y[ i ]
  } )
}

/**
 * Create the chart
 */
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "graphs": [ {
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletSize": 8,
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "xField": "x",
    "yField": "y",
  } ]
} );
```

Here's a working demo of the above:

http://codepen.io/amcharts/pen/15b2c710357a7e29eda11dc5caa07d44

Comment: Thanks alot! Too bad I can't use arrays directly, but glad I can use detailed x values now.

Comment: Glad that helped. I must admit though, I don't quite understand why you can't  use arrays? I don't have experience with Python, but I'm pretty sure there's a way to transfer native arrays in Python to a JSON when generating the web page. Or am I completely off track here?

Comment: When I generate a JSON from Python for lets say two lines with each 3 points it looks like this:

`{
  "result": [
    [
      1.2,
      2.0,
      3.5
],
[
     4,
     3,
     7.5
]
}`

And in other charts I could address this data with "data.result[0]" for the first line etc. Maybe add a field for the x axis too, but that's how I would expect a chart to accept data.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. That does not change a lot. It's just instead of "x" you would use data.result[0] and instead of "y" - data.result[0]. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well, what I expect would be, that I could enter the data like this: `{x = [1,2,3,4], y: [5,6,7,8]}` but it seems like this is not working. So I really have to add an "x:" before every value? That would increase the JSON request by a huge amount, or I would have to loop over all my data to make it a proper json string afterwards - so much calculation, just because amCharts doesn't accept arrays?

Comment: amCharts does not accept arrays. But the 4-line code I provided does transfer your array format into amCharts-compatible format. I think it's a reasonable solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is indeed a working solution. But since I plan to update 10k points 20-30 times a second, I'm not sure if it will be fast enough - I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

following is the simpliest definition possible. The [dateProvider](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#dataProvider) is an array of objects where each element represents the x-axis item with it's y values.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("your element id",{
    "type": "serial",
    "pathToImages": "http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
    "categoryField": "category",
    "graphs": [
        {
            "valueField": "column-1"
        }
    ],
    "dataProvider": [
        {
            "category": "1",
            "column-1": "8"
        },
        {
            "category": "2",
            "column-1": 6
        },
        {
            "category": "3",
            "column-1": 2
        },
        {
            "category": "4",
            "column-1": 1
        }
    ]
});
```

Live sample:
http://live.amcharts.com/2JmYT/edit/

Comment: Thank you - that a great example too explain my problems:

How to properly transfer my arrays/lists (in Python) to make them acceptable by amChart? My first wild guess would be to create a for loop which would make a string, adding all those brackets and written names ("column-1, category").
But this feels extremely wrong, if not totally unclean and slow.

And secondly: Changing `"category": "1",` to  `"category": "1.323"` doesn't bring the desired result - the x value is still at one instead of 1.323.

Comment: Ok, one step better for problem (1) might be to create a kind of dict that jsonify will automatically encode properly, so I might not need to add the bracket and stuff manually, but still a bit weird and time consuming.