# How do I apply y Axis min and max values ​to a chart of type: xy?

Tags: amcharts

I want to apply minimum 0 and maximum 1 to the y and x axes of a type: xy graph in html.

in EJS, i graphed the code from the first answer in [Creating a "normal" line chart in amcharts.js with arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062352/creating-a-normal-line-chart-in-amcharts-js-with-arrays)

html

```
<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
```

js

```
var y = [0,0.8481,1];
var y0 = [0,0.5,1];
var y1 = [0,0.8957,1];
var y2 = [0,0.9088,1];
var y3 = [0,0.6256,0.6745,0.8911,1];
var x = [0,0.0342,1];
var x0 = [0,0.5,1];
var x1 = [0,0.1152,1];
var x2 = [0,0.0297,1];
var x3 = [0,0.0297,0.0342,0.1152,1];
var chartData = [];

for( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
  chartData.push( {
    "x": x[ i ],
    "y": y[ i ],
    "x0": x0[ i ],
    "y0": y0[ i ],
    "y1": y1[ i ],
    "x1": x1[ i ],
    "y2": y2[ i ],
    "x2": x2[ i ],
  } )
}

for( var i = 0; i < x3.length; i++ ) {
  chartData.push( {
    "y3": y3[ i ],
    "x3": x3[ i ]
  } );
}
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv2",{
  "type": "xy",
  "pathToImages": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "graphs": [
    {
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x",
      "yField": "y",
    },{
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x1",
      "yField": "y1",
    },{
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x2",
      "yField": "y2",
    },{
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x3",
      "yField": "y3",
    },{
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x0",
      "yField": "y0",
    }
  ],"yAxes": [{
    "type": "ValueAxis",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1
  }],"xAxes": [{
    "type": "ValueAxis",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1
  }]

});
```

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/value-axis/

```
"yAxes": [{
    "type": "ValueAxis",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1
  }],"xAxes": [{
    "type": "ValueAxis",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1
  }]
```

Applying the code above does not change the minimum and maximum of the y and x axes to 0 and 1.
in addition, i'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the two versions up. The value axis documentation you linked to is for version 4, whereas the majority of your code (and the linked stackoverflow question) is using [version 3](http://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/#xy-bubble), which defines [value axes](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/valueaxis/) like this:

```
"valueAxes": [{
  "minimum": 0,
  "maximum": 1,
  "position": "left"
},{
  "minimum": 0,
  "maximum": 1,
  "position": "bottom"
}]
```

Updated demo using version 3:

```js
var y = [0,0.8481,1];
var y0 = [0,0.5,1];
var y1 = [0,0.8957,1];
var y2 = [0,0.9088,1];
var y3 = [0,0.6256,0.6745,0.8911,1];
var x = [0,0.0342,1];
var x0 = [0,0.5,1];
var x1 = [0,0.1152,1];
var x2 = [0,0.0297,1];
var x3 = [0,0.0297,0.0342,0.1152,1];
var chartData = [];

for( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
  chartData.push( {
    "x": x[ i ],
    "y": y[ i ],
    "x0": x0[ i ],
    "y0": y0[ i ],
    "y1": y1[ i ],
    "x1": x1[ i ],
    "y2": y2[ i ],
    "x2": x2[ i ],
  } )
}

for( var i = 0; i < x3.length; i++ ) {
  chartData.push( {
    "y3": y3[ i ],
    "x3": x3[ i ]
  } );
}
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv2",{
  "type": "xy",
  "pathToImages": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "graphs": [
    {
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x",
      "yField": "y",
    },{
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x1",
      "yField": "y1",
    },{
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x2",
      "yField": "y2",
    },{
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x3",
      "yField": "y3",
    },{
      "bullet": null,
      "bulletSize": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "xField": "x0",
      "yField": "y0",
    }
  ],"yAxes": [{
    "type": "ValueAxis",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1
  }],"xAxes": [{
    "type": "ValueAxis",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv2" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```